# Is it right to rgister the controller to a keylisttenr class in MVC model?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I write a game in java with MVC pattern.

In this game, I use a keyListener class, to move an object.
is it the right way of thinking to register the control class to the keyListener and every time that event will occur the controller will update by the keyListener?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's the view's job to establish the link between the user and the controller.  Unless there's some overriding reason to avoid it, it's reasonable for the view to:

1. Attach a key listener that calls the controller when the key state changes, whenever the user is being shown an object that the key controls; and
2. Detach the key listener whenever the user is not being shown an object that the key controls.